# Can I change the root directory for dir format maven assemblies?

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I'm using an assembly descriptor of the "dir" format to produce an exploded distributable. Currently this places the files I include in a directory named "target/${project.build.finalName}".

I would ideally like this directory to be named differently. Ideally "target/${project.artifactId}", essentially dropping the version component.

The reason for wanting this change is that I'm going to need to refer to files in that archive in a discrete pipeline step, and having the version in the path presents maintainability issues.

Simplified version of the assembly descriptor provided:

```
<assembly>
  <id>preparation</id>
  <formats>
    <format>dir</format>
  </formats>
  <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>

  <fileSets>
    <fileSet>
      <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
      <outputDirectory/>
      </excludes>
    </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

Where I currently end up with a root dir like:

```
target/myArtifactId-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/assembledResources
```

and I would like to arrive at

```
target/myArtifactId/assembledResources
```

baseDirectory and friends only affect the paths within the root directory, still leaving me with a path which includes a version number, like:

```
target/myArtifactId-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/myArtifactId/assembledResources
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your maven maven-assembly-plugin configure the `<finalName>` to be `${project.artifactId}`

**Note**:
In the example below, change the location of `<descriptor>src/assembly/dist.xml</descriptor>` to your location.

For example:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <descriptors>
            <descriptor>src/assembly/dist.xml</descriptor>
        </descriptors>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I'm assuming that you don't want the  "preparation" appended to the name so I included `<appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>`